# How to continuously manipulate other website data?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web, code-injection

I have used JS injector extensions on chrome to manipulate data on other website ( to see things in the way I want it to be ) but this method doesn't work on websites where the data is continuously changing.

For example, lets say I open Yahoo Finance where stock data is displayed live. I want to manipulate that data, meaning whatever live data is being displayed I want to multiply 100 to them and see that happening live and continuously. Is there any way to apply JS injection ( onchange ) kind of function to detect change and multiply 100x right away.

Comment: No, there's no generic way to "_detect change and multiply 100x_", the approach totally depends on how the changes are made on the page.

Comment: How to change data that is streaming live?

Comment: For example if you go to yahoo finance, you can see live data of NASDAQ, GOLD, S&P500 etc. That data is being displayed in a specific format, I want to multiply 100 to all and then would like to see the live stream. Is that possible?

Comment: Questions on SO must stand on their own content. If you in the post can clearly explain, how exactly the data is presented on that page, and how it changes, and show an attempt to scrape that data, you might get an answer, or at least some guidance.